# Stopping a Subscription Bomb

Tags: gmail, regex, filter

Are there any methods for stopping a subscription bomb other than issuing a new email address? Creating gmail filters is only getting us so far as there are more emails coming in than we can keep up with. It feels like a losing battle.

Is there a regex we can use to stop all non-english characters? I've tried a non-ascii pattern but that is matching legitimate emails with hidden characters.

If we can stop the non-english emails that is a good start

Comment: What you mean by "subscription bomb?"

Comment: @ThoriumBR someone takes an email address and signs them up for thousands and thousands of subscriptions, registering accounts with websites from all over the world. There are services on the dark web to do it, or you can script something yourself

Comment: Are those websites sending a "confirm subscription" email? If they are, ignore them. If they aren't, you could contact them about GDPR...